# How to check more efficiently if every key in a std::map has been called

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, vector, mapping

I know the title is weird but i don'y know how to say this, here is a really poor example of what i usually use:

```
void exercise1(std::vector<bool> &MyVec) {
    std::cout << "Exercise 1";

    MyVec.at(0) = true;
}

void exercise2(std::vector<bool> &MyVec) {
    std::cout << "Exercise 2";

    MyVec.at(1) = true;
}

int main() {
    int answer;
    std::map<int, std::function<void(std::vector<bool> &MyVec)>> exercises = {
        {1, exercise1},
        {2, exercise2}
    };
    std::vector<bool> wasSeen(2);

    std::fill(wasSeen.begin(), wasSeen.end(), false);

    // assuming the user can only input the digits 1 and 2
    do {
        std::cout << "What exercise do you want to look at?\n (1 to 2)";
        std::cin >> answer;

        exercises.at(answer)(wasSeen);
    } while (std::adjacent_find(wasSeen.begin(), wasSeen.end(), std::not_equal_to<>()) != wasSeen.end());
    
    // do other stuff after all the functions get called

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Is there a more efficient way of checking if every **function from the map** has been called than using the **bool vector wasSeen** and always checking all of its values?

Comment: better to define set and keep the input in set and check if that input is already processed or not.

Comment: You could store a bool alongside the function (as a std::pair) in the map. When the entry is accessed, if the flag is false, set it to true and increment a counter (i.e. you are incrementing the counter once for each entry). Then all you have to do is compare the value of the counter with the size of the map.

Comment: @JonathanPotter could you please provide some code examples? I've never used any of the functions you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `std::set` to store the index of the functions you already called. Because a `std::set` only stores unique elements, you know that all functions have been called when the size of the set equals the size of the map:

```
 std::set<int> already_called_funcs;

 do {
     int index = my_random_index();
     exercises[index](some_vector);
     already_called_funcs.insert(index);
 } while( already_called_funcs.size() != exercises.size());
```

However, if you want to call every function only once inside the loop you should actually do the reverse: Populate a container with all possible indices, then choose a random element from that container, call the respective function, and remove the index from the container. In that way you do not have to reroll random numbers until you find an index that was not used before.

Comment: What would happen if the user chooses to look at the same exercise twice while using std::set?  This is not the case, this was just an example but i'm wondering what happens if someone inserts a already existing value in a set

Comment: @akaManen elements in `std::set` are unique. If the set contains eg `1` and you insert `1` then afterwards the set still contains one `1` (insert returns a `bool` which tells you if the insertion actually took place)